# SetOption for AxesStyle and AxesLabels differently

Tags: plotting, options

I can set the Options for `Plot` as:

```
SetOptions[
  Plot, 
  AxesStyle -> 
 {{Black, 14, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"}, 
 {Black, 14, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"}}];
```

But it also changes the style on the labels themselves (which I want in a different style), e.g., "x" and "y" in this example:

```
Plot[Cos[x],
 {x, -5, 5},
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

How can I set the Options for the added labels to be separate from the rest of the AxesStyle?  As an example, suppose I want the "x" and "y" to be Red, Bold, and 28 points?

Of course I can *hand code* those styles each time into the AxesLabel specifications, but I'd like to do it with Options.

Comment: Add the options `FontColor -> Red`, `FontWeight -> Bold` when you set `AxesStyle`?

Comment: @kglr:  Nope.  Doesn't work:  It makes *all* the text red.  And note that I want the size of the axes ticks to be different from the "x" and "y" labels too.

Comment: sorry; i see...

Comment: maybe add the option `TicksStyle -> FontColor -> Black` to override the `FontColor ->Red` in set in `AxesStyle`?

Comment: @kglr:  You set me on the right track; override was the key.  `SetOptions[Plot,
  Sequence[
   AxesStyle -> {{28, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times", 
      FontColor -> Red}, {28, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times", 
      FontColor -> Red}}],
  TicksStyle -> {{14, FontColor -> Black}, {14, FontColor -> Black}}];`  Post that and I'll accept it.

Comment: you can use the simpler `SetOptions[Plot, { AxesStyle -> Directive[28, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times", FontColor -> Red], TicksStyle -> Directive[14, FontColor -> Black]}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon:  Thanks, but as I stated, I could hand code labels explicitly (each time) as you suggest, but wanted to instead set an Option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the font settings given in `AxesStyle` using `TicksStyle`:

```
SetOptions[Plot, 
  {AxesStyle -> Directive[28, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times", FontColor -> Red], 
   TicksStyle -> Directive[14, FontColor -> Black]}]

Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y"}]
```

[image]

Comment: I really do dislike how `TicksStyle` is misnamed... it's really more like `TickLabelStyle`.